# How can I push element to array in http.put in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  projects: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Project'}],
  //....
}
```

How can I add `projectId` by using `http.put`?

This is among the things that I have tried:

```
$http.put('/api/users/'+User._id, {'projects': project._id});
```

Comment: you want to have `projects': project._id` in UserSchema object?

Comment: Does your API controller support this action?  Are you in control of the REST Service?From what I see you are using Microsoft WebApi.  If that is the case you need to code  your controller to do this or, look into using the ODATA controller instead.

Comment: I am creating a many-to-many relation between Users and Projects. Thought this was the way to do it?
I am using the angular fullstack generator. In other words; yes, I am in control of the REST Service, and it is not a Microsoft WebApi.

Comment: I have it the same way in ProjectSchema (array of user id's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it using:

`$http.put('/api/users/'+User._id, {'projects': User.projects});`

and in my update method:

`_.extend(user, req.body);`

instead of

`_.merge(user, req.body);`